# How can I efficiently filter a PySpark data frame with conditions listed in the dictionary?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, filter

How can I efficiently filter a PySpark data frame with conditions listed in the dictionary without using any for loops? For example, I have this data frame (df) as below.
[image]
And I have a dictionary of conditions with keys as product_pt_family and values as acceptance_rate, i.e.,

```
dict1= {'Fruits & Vegetables’: 85, 'Dairy & Eggs': 90,'Water':91,'Bakery':92}
```

I want to filter out the data frame with these conditions, i.e., get the data frame rows whose acceptance rate exceeds the dictionary value of the corresponding product_pt_family.

i.e., if the pt_family is "Fruits & Vegetables," then get only those rows whose acceptance rate is >= 85; if the pt_family is "Water," get only those rows whose acceptance rate is >= 91, and so on.

So the final data frame after filtering with this dictionary is:
[image]

The code that I tried to obtain this final data frame with the dictionary is

```
pt_families=list(set(df.select('product_pt_family').toPandas()['product_pt_family']))


schema= df.schema


thresholded_df=spark.createDataFrame([], schema)


for pt_family in  pt_families:


        df_1=df.filter((df.product_pt_family==pt_family ) & (df.acceptance_rate>=dict1[pt_family]))


        thresholded_df=thresholded_df.union(df_1)
     
thresholded_df.show()
```

`

This takes a lot of time. Is there any quick and effective way of filtering the data frame without using for loops and unions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using a custom udf function?

Comment: Are you fine with looping over schema (not dataframe) to create single expression that can be used in the filter?

Comment: Hi @HoangMinhQuangFX15045 Hoang, I am new to PySpark, so I have never tried to use UDF until now. As I have learned that UDF functions are not that recommended to use, could you please help me on how to write the UDF function for it?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @RonakJain Ronak, I did not fully understand looping over schema; could you please help me with the code that you are suggesting? Thanks

Comment: Sure, will answer

Comment: @krishnakaushik Added my answer, let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated my result without using Spark UDF and any loop statements.

Let's assume this is your DataFrame (df):

```
+--------+-------------------+---------------+
| item_id|  product_pt_family|acceptance_rate|
+--------+-------------------+---------------+
|51259338|Fruits & Vegetables|          81.45|
|22660282|Fruits & Vegetables|           98.5|
|10450119|       Dairy & Eggs|          89.65|
|10450118|       Dairy & Eggs|          90.32|
+--------+-------------------+---------------+
```

1. Convert your dictionary into a DataFrame

```
threshold_dict = {'Fruits & Vegetables': 85, 'Dairy & Eggs': 90}

threshold_df = spark.createDataFrame(threshold_dict.items(), schema="product_pt_family STRING, threshold_rate INT")
```

2. Use join to get desired output

```
joined_df = df.join(threshold_df, "product_pt_family")

out_df = joined_df.filter("acceptance_rate >= threshold_rate").drop("threshold_rate")

out_df.show()
```

***Output:***

```
+-------------------+--------+---------------+
|  product_pt_family| item_id|acceptance_rate|
+-------------------+--------+---------------+
|       Dairy & Eggs|10450118|          90.32|
|Fruits & Vegetables|22660282|           98.5|
+-------------------+--------+---------------+
```

Comment: Yes, But I have updated my result without using Spark UDF and any loop statement. Kindly check :)

Comment: Hi @arudsekaberne, wow, this is also an excellent way of filtering; thanks a lot for the answer. Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @arudsekaberne Nice approach, but I would still avoid any kind of join (as it would mean shuffle, even if small) especially when it is a simple operation like a filter.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use UDF, also UDF should be avoided unless inevitable as their implementation is unknown to Catalyst Optimizer thus impact the plan. Spark suggests using in-build

This would work:

```
dict1= {'Fruits & Vegetables': 85, 'Dairy & Eggs': 90}

conditions = (F.lit(1) == F.lit(0)) # Or conditions thus won't impact
for family, rate in dict1.items():
      conditions = (conditions) | ((F.col("product_pt_family") == family) & (F.col("acceptance_rate") >= rate))
        
df\
 .filter(conditions)\
 .show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

```
+-------+-------------------+---------------+
|item_id|product_pt_family  |acceptance_rate|
+-------+-------------------+---------------+
|1      |Fruits & Vegetables|88.96          |
|2      |Fruits & Vegetables|80.96          |
|3      |Dairy & Eggs       |80.0           |
|4      |Fruits & Vegetables|91.0           |
|5      |Dairy & Eggs       |95.0           |
+-------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------------------+---------------+
|item_id|product_pt_family  |acceptance_rate|
+-------+-------------------+---------------+
|1      |Fruits & Vegetables|88.96          |
|4      |Fruits & Vegetables|91.0           |
|5      |Dairy & Eggs       |95.0           |
+-------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Interesting!, I haven't tried in this way yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @RonakJain Ronak, for the answer. I highly appreciate your help!